# No command 'foo' found even though 'foo' is intsalled

Tags: python, path, command, terminal-emulator

I just installed django by typing `pip install django` but I can't use it now by typing `django startproject sitename`. The output is:

```
No command 'django' found, did you mean: 

   some suggestions here
```

When I try to type `pip install django` again, I get:

```
Requirement already satisfied: django in
`/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages`
```

**How can I solve this problem?**

---

`echo $HOME` returns `/data/data/com.termux/files/home` .

`echo $PATH` returns `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin:/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/applets`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing the *package* `foo` does not necessarily provide a *command* `foo`. In the case of django, the command is

```
django-admin startproject <name>
```

And depending on where things are installed, you may still need to modify your PATH.

Comment: Oh gosh. Didn't remember correct command properly and I was wondering why the error popped up. Thank you for your help.